# How to Get the Real Time if user has modified the Android Device Time to do backdate entries in database?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, android-studio

I have an app which books only between a certain period of time in the day.
If user changes the Device time then he will able to book even after the time is gone.

Please Help me...

Comment: Get Time from web service... like [this time api](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now). Without internet, you will not found any safe solution

Comment: I presume that application uses internet communication?

Comment: If bookings are stored on your server, add extra validation for booking time on the server side.

Comment: @AxelH HOW TO USE TIME API, in java

Comment: This is a simple webservice, just need to use a HttpUrlConnection in Java to call the url, just do some research about this. (you will need the internet permission).